# What if the string.xml not contain enough language strings

Tags: android, apk

i am trying to translate my Chinese app to English language....i used apk tool and decompiled them already, but the res/value/ string.xml not contain enough strings for the whole app...so i want to know anywhere in APK file that contain the language file like string.xml?

Comment: Those strings are converted to Java raw code...This doesn't make sense tho..if you made the chinese app, then you must be having it's code.

Comment: You are trying to reverse engineering the apk?

Comment: you don't need to decompile **your own app**. You can open it's source code, and modify it. Unless it is not your own app.

Comment: It not my own app...i mean it was someone else app....but it is in Chinese language so i want to translate it in English...but i have problem finding out where to modify the language files...i though it might be in Smali folder but dont know where